# How do I get the username of a Telegram user in the main function of a python Telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm programming a Telegram bot in python using the library `python-telegram-bot`, but I have a problem: I need to get the username of the user (sorry for the pun), but I don't know how to do it in the main function. I have already searched on the internet, and everyone get the username in a function, using `update.message.from_user.username`. But I need to do it in the main function, because I want to send this username and some text to another Telegram user. Can you help me?

My current code is this:

```
import telegram
import logging
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, Updater
from functions import start, button

bot = telegram.Bot(token='')
updater = Updater(token='')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s'
                    ' - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
updater.stop()
```

Comment: Could you please share your current code?

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're looking for:

```
def start (update, context):

    #this will retrieve the user's username, as you already know
    user = update.message.from_user

    #this will send the information to some Telegram user
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id = some_user_chat_id,
                             text = f'User {user} just hit start command!')
```

Once the user hit `/start` command, his/her username will be sent to the `chat_id` of your choice.

Comment: Not exactly, because with this code I get the username in the start function, and I wanted to do it in the main function

Answer (score 0):

You can set middleware which handle new update from user and get username throw ctx.from.username